# How to predict future values with deep learning?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, prediction

I'm using a deep learning algorithm for price prediction in cryptocurrency markets. This code is only predicting dates which are already in datasets. Code is using unix time as date input. How can i get future predictions?

My dataset is from 1 Aug 2015 to 1 Aug 2020.
I want to predict 1 Aug 2020 - 1 Sep 2020; but it predicts to 1 Aug 2020 last.

Shortly, I want to predict the dates which are not included already in my dataset.

```
def train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2):
    split_row = len(df) - int(test_size * len(df))
    train_data = df.iloc[:split_row]
    test_data = df.iloc[split_row:]
    return train_data, test_data
train, test = train_test_split(hist, test_size=0.2)

def line_plot(line1, line2, label1=None, label2=None, title=Crypto, lw=2):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(13, 7))
    ax.plot(line1, label=label1, linewidth=lw)
    ax.plot(line2, label=label2, linewidth=lw)
    ax.set_ylabel('price [USD]', fontsize=14)
    #ax.set_xlabel('Time [day]', fontsize=14)
    ax.set_title(title, fontsize=16)
    ax.legend(loc='best', fontsize=16)
line_plot(train[target_col], test[target_col], 'training', 'test', title='')

def normalise_zero_base(df):
    return df / df.iloc[0] - 1

def normalise_min_max(df):
    return (df - df.min()) / (df.max() - df.min())

def extract_window_data(df, window_len=5, zero_base=True):
    window_data = []
    for idx in range(len(df) - window_len):
        tmp = df[idx: (idx + window_len)].copy()
        if zero_base:
            tmp = normalise_zero_base(tmp)
        window_data.append(tmp.values)
    return np.array(window_data)

def prepare_data(df, target_col, window_len=10, zero_base=True, test_size=0.2):
    train_data, test_data = train_test_split(df, test_size=test_size)
    X_train = extract_window_data(train_data, window_len, zero_base)
    X_test = extract_window_data(test_data, window_len, zero_base)
    y_train = train_data[target_col][window_len:].values
    y_test = test_data[target_col][window_len:].values
    if zero_base:
        y_train = y_train / train_data[target_col][:-window_len].values - 1
        y_test = y_test / test_data[target_col][:-window_len].values - 1

    return train_data, test_data, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test

def build_lstm_model(input_data, output_size, neurons=100, activ_func='linear', dropout=0.2, loss='mse', optimizer='adam'):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(neurons, input_shape=(input_data.shape[1], input_data.shape[2])))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))
    model.add(Dense(units=output_size))
    model.add(Activation(activ_func))
    model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=optimizer)
    return model

np.random.seed(42)
window_len = 5
test_size = 0.2
zero_base = True
lstm_neurons = 100
epochs = 100
batch_size = 32
loss = 'mse'
dropout = 0.2
optimizer = 'adam'

train, test, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = prepare_data(
    hist, target_col, window_len=window_len, zero_base=zero_base, test_size=test_size)
model = build_lstm_model(
    X_train, output_size=1, neurons=lstm_neurons, dropout=dropout, loss=loss,
    optimizer=optimizer)
history = model.fit(
    X_train, y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1, shuffle=True)

targets = test[target_col][window_len:]
preds = model.predict(X_test).squeeze()
mean_absolute_error(preds, y_test)
# 0.027955859325876943

preds = test[target_col].values[:-window_len] * (preds + 1)
preds = pd.Series(index=targets.index, data=preds)
line_plot(targets, preds, 'actual', 'prediction', lw=3)
```

[image: Dataset example]
Dataset example photo

[image: Training]
Training Output Photo

[image: Prediction]
Prediction Output Photo

Comment: What have you tried so far, what's not working the way you like. Basically what is the code you're showing us? :)

Comment: Sorry i'm new in here :(

My dataset is from 1 Aug 2015 to 1 Aug 2020.
I want to predict 1 Aug 2020 - 1 Sep 2020; but it predicts to 1 Aug 2020 last.

Basically i want to predict the dates which are not included already in dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you use 10 time steps to forecast the following time step. If you want to predict the future price with your trained model you have to use your predictions as input.

The following figure allows you better understand how it works. The `*` indicates a predicted value, opposed to real values. So `1 ... 8 9 10` are your 10 latest real values . The `->` indicates your model function.

```
input -> output*

1 ... 8 9 10 -> 11*

2 ... 9 10 11* -> 12*

3 ... 10 11* 12* -> 13*

...

n-9* ... n-2* n-1* n* -> n+1*
```

Comment: But my code don't predicts forward, Isn't it?

1 ... 8 9 10 -> 10*